# Getting data from an ArrayList in one class to another

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

So I'm trying to display the data stored in an ArrayList of one class Liquor into another class Bar. The ArrayList holds 5 Strings (name of liquor) and 5 ints (amount for each liquor in stock). When I run the code to display the info I get a very long error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at barinventory.BarInv.jButtonDisplayActionPerformed(BarInv.java:355)
>     at barinventory.BarInv.access$200(BarInv.java:8)    at
>   barinventory.BarInv$3.actionPerformed(BarInv.java:219)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   BUILD STOPPED (total time: 12 seconds)

My Liquor class:

```
final class Liquor
{
    //String[] liquor = {"Vodka", "Whiskey", "Rum", "Gin", "Brandy"};
    private final String vodka, whiskey, rum, gin, brandy;
    private final int vCount, wCount, rCount, gCount, bCount;
    ArrayList<Liquor> liquors = new ArrayList<>();

//    public Liquor(ArrayList<Liquor> liquors)
//    {
//        
//        this.vodka = "Vodka";
//        this.whiskey = "Whiskey";
//        this.rum = "Rum";
//        this.gin = "Gin";
//        this.brandy = "Brandy";
//        this.vCount = getVC();
//        this.wCount = getWC();
//        this.rCount = getRC();
//        this.gCount = getGC();
//        this.bCount = getBC();
//    } was trying to pass it through the ArrayList itself... Didn't work.
      //The stock number kept being read in as 0.



    public Liquor(String vodka, String whiskey, String rum, String gin, 
            String brandy, int v, int w, int r, int g, int b)
    {
        this.vodka = vodka;
        this.whiskey = whiskey;
        this.rum = rum;
        this.gin = gin;
        this.brandy = brandy;
        this.vCount = v;
        this.wCount = w;
        this.rCount = r;
        this.gCount = g;
        this.bCount = b;
    }

    public String getV()
    {
        return vodka;
    }

    public String getW()
    {
        return whiskey;
    }

    public String getR()
    {
        return rum;
    }

    public String getG()
    {
        return gin;
    }

    public String getB()
    {
        return brandy;
    }

    public int getVC()
    {
        return vCount;
    }

    public int getWC()
    {
        return wCount;
    }

    public int getRC()
    {
        return rCount;
    }

    public int getGC()
    {
        return gCount;
    }

    public int getBC()
    {
        return bCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\nLiquor currently in stock:\n" + vodka + ": " + vCount + "\n" +
                whiskey + ": " + wCount + "\n" + rum + ": " + rCount + "\n" +
                gin + ": " + gCount + "\n" + brandy + ": " + bCount;
    }
}
```

My bar class:

```
class Bar
{
    private final String barLoc, barName;
    private final boolean music, food;
    //ArrayList<Liquor> liquor;

    public Bar(String l, String n, boolean m, boolean f)
    {
        this.barLoc = l;
        this.barName = n;
        this.music = m;
        this.food = f;
    }

    //ArrayList<Liquor> liquor = new ArrayList<>();
    private Liquor liquor;

    public Liquor getLiquor()
    {
        return liquor;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "The " + barLoc + " bar is named: " + barName + "\nLive music: " 
                + music + "\nFood Service: " + food;
    } 
}
```

Code used for the display:

```
for(int i=0; i<bars.size(); i++)
        {
            jTextAreaDisplay.append(jTextAreaDisplay.getText() 
                    + bars.get(i).toString() + bars.get(i).getLiquor().toString() 
                    + "\n\n");

        }
```

I think the problem has to do with initializing the  `private Liquor liquor;` in my Bar class, which I've tried in different ways. But atlas can't get it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example run:

> The (barLocation) bar is named: (barName)
>
> Live music: (true or false)
>
> Food Service: (true or false)
>
> Liquor currently in stock:
>
> Vodka: (amount of stock)
>
> Whiskey: (amount of stock)
>
> Rum: (amount of stock)
>
> Gin: (amount of stock)
>
> Brandy: (amount of stock)

Comment: you're right - you're not initializing liquor property at all, but trying to call method on it

Comment: replace `bars.get(i).getLiquor().toString() ` with `bars.get(i).getLiquor()` to get rid of exception, but this will not fix your logical problem

Comment: You'll also be disappointed with the results of ArrayList#toString

Comment: Okay, so how can I read in the data? Rather how do I initialize my liquor properly?

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I can see you never initialized liquor.

The initialization would look like this

```
Liquor liquor = new Liquor("data", "data", ...);
```

I don´t get the purpose of creating one single liquor object that contains more liquids (vodka, etc.). But maybe you have your reasons.
If not then I would design Liquor differently because what you did doesn´t really resemble reality.
Normally the class Liquor should have properties somewhere like this:

```
public String name;
public double alcohol;
```

Then I would create a ArrayList of Liquors in your bar and fill it with some values.

```
ArrayList<Liquor> liquors = new ArrayList<Liquor>();
//Fill with something like 4 liquors i call them vodka 0, 1, 2 and 3 and fill them with the alcohol value of 40
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  liquors.add(new Liquor("Wodka"+i, 40));
}
```

Now my fill-method obviously requires your Liquid class to have a constructor with 2 parameters (String name, int alcohol)

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the Liquor object.Try the following statement

```
private Liquor liquor=new Liquor("vodka",""...,1,2,..);
```